# Deleting selected row in MySQL database through JTable

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jtable, sql-delete

- tb_records = jtable name
- records = table name inside my database
- Date = my first column
- hey = substitute for my real password
- mydatabase = name of my database

My problem is that, when I highlight a row in my JTable and delete it, it deletes all the rows. I want to delete the selected row only. Here's my code:

```
int row = tb_records.getSelectedRow();
DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel)tb_records.getModel();

String selected = model.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();

            if (row >= 0) {

                model.removeRow(row);

                try {
                    Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase", "root", "hey");
                    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("delete from records where Date='"+selected+"' ");
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
                catch (Exception w) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Connection Error!");
                }           
            }
```

What could be the problem here? How can I delete a selected row in my database and not all the rows?

Comment: I could use some help right here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535629/record-not-getting-deleted-from-mysql-databases-table-while-its-deleted-from-j

Answer (score 1):

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
        int row = jTable.getSelectedRow();
        String eve = jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).

        String delRow = "delete from user where id="+eve;
        try {
            ps = myCon.getConnection().prepareStatement(delRow);
            ps.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulation !!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't display your own message. Display the error message from the Exception as it will give a better explanation what the problem is.

2) Use a proper PreparedStatement for the SQL. You are less likely to make syntax errors. Something like:

```
String sql = "delete from records where Date= ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString( 1, selected );
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

I don't know much about SQL but maybe you need to pass a Date object not a String object since your where clause is using a Date?

Comment: Ok.. I'll do that next time

Comment: I solved my problem but it gives me another problem which is, it deletes all the rows not the selected row. I'll revise my question.

Comment: @user2942600, `Ok.. I'll do that next time` - don't wait until the next time. It will take 2 minutes to do it now. `deletes all the rows not the selected row` probably because your "where" clause is too general. It will delete all rows with the same date. You need a more specific way to specify the row to be deleted.

Comment: You're right. My Date column has the same data. I tried it in different column with unique values and it worked. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @user2942600, 1. `I tried it in different column with unique values and it worked` then why isn't the answer accepted? 2. Since you changed the code, why didn't you use the PreparedStatment properly then way I suggested above? There is no time like the present to learn how use the API the way it was designed to be used. The minutue you spend now will save you plenty of time in the future by avoiding the need to debug SQL syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> **SOLUTION**: Pick a column with unique values. My Date column has the same values that's why it's deleting all my rows even though I set my row as getSelectedRow. Time_in = my 4th column with unique values.
>
> change
>
> ```
> String selected = model.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> String selected = model.getValueAt(row, 3).toString();
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("delete from records where Date='"+selected+"' ");
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("delete from records where Time_in='"+selected+"' ");
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)